# How to manage SharePoint configuration?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are planning to rebuild our intranet on SP 2010 and are planning to have department sites (among others) where one or more people will be able to edit the page, add/remove web parts, etc. I'm concerned about managing this configuration between environments such as production/test. I'd like to know how people go about doing this? Manually? Are there tools to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a simple question with an enormously complex answer: Welcome to Governance.

Overview:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263356.aspx

Topics covered:

**Governance overview (SharePoint Server 2010)**

This article introduces governance as an essential part of a successful SharePoint Server 2010 deployment and explains the various components of an enterprise governance plan.

**Governance features (SharePoint Server 2010)**

This article reviews a set of SharePoint Server 2010 features that an organization can use to help govern an IT service, information management, and information architecture.

**Establishing and governing a SharePoint service (SharePoint Server 2010)**

Learn about key factors in governing a SharePoint service and what to include in a service-level agreement.

**Implementing and governing information architecture (SharePoint Server 2010)**

Learn how to plan an effective information architecture to ensure that your solution meets your business needs.

**Plan for sandboxed solutions (SharePoint Server 2010)**

This article explains how to plan to use sandboxed solutions in a SharePoint environment.

Book excerpt: SharePoint Development and Governance Using COBIT 4.1: A Practical Approach

These book excerpts are from "SharePoint Deployment and Governance Using COBIT® 4.1: A Practical Approach."

**SharePoint 2010 Governance Planning (white paper)**

This white paper focuses on the “front end” of the SharePoint environment – the business aspect of governance - the areas that effect business users. It uses a fictitious company to provide guidance for the necessary governance planning and implementation of SharePoint Server 2010.

**Implementing Governance in SharePoint 2010 (white paper)**

This white paper focuses on the “back end” of SharePoint governance – the technical implementation. It provides high-level guidance on the many configuration options that SharePoint Server 2010 provides to enable you to manage the environment for the benefit of all.

Comment: Good stuff, but let me walk through a scenario and maybe you can point me in the right direction. If I have people in a production environment who are editing a page, maybe adding a web part to a page, how can I keep my test environment in sync with these changes?

Comment: Periodically 'rolldown' your live sharepoint to your test/qa. Google backing up and restoring content databases.